# Pencil drawing on mouseDragged event on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

How to make pencil-drawing on a JPanel via mouseDragged ?

I have a JPanel where I want to draw using the mouse, so whenever I drag the mouse on that JPanel, for each (x,y) an oval shape (with specified color and dimension) is painted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways to do custom painting:

1. Create a List of Objects you want to paint and then iterate through the List every time the component is repainted.
2. Paint the objects directly to a BufferedImage and then when the component is repainted you paint the BufferedImage.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of both approaches. The example actually draws colored Rectangles which is almost exactly what you want.